# Why does bash appear faster on an Ubuntu VM than on the host MacOS?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, osx, virtual-machine, performance

This is the laptop sitting in front of me right now:

[image]

On it is installed VMWare Fusion 8.5.3 with an Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit VM.  I ran the following little test to compare performance between bash on the host and bash on the VM:

```
time for i in {1..1000000}; do :; done
```

Note that the stock bash version on MacOS is 3.2.57, so I downloaded and built the same version to run on the VM to ensure a fair comparison.

**The results - The VM is more than 2x as fast as the host**!

#### Host (MacOS)

```
mymac:~ me$ time for i in {1..1000000}; do :; done

real    0m4.608s
user    0m4.536s
sys 0m0.067s
mymac:~ me$
```

#### VM (Ubuntu)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ time for i in {1..1000000}; do :; done            

real    0m2.146s
user    0m2.136s
sys 0m0.008s
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

How can the VM be so much faster when it should be effectively running the same code on (a virtualized form of) the same CPU?

---

#### Notes

- The MacOS host has 8 logical cores and 16GB RAM.  I have assigned only 2 logical cores and 2GB RAM to the VM.  I think this should make little difference - this test is not memory bound and is single-threaded.
- I powered off the VM while running the host test
- I ran strace on the Ubuntu bash process.  As expected there just a handful of syscalls at the start and end of the test, and no syscalls during the bulk of the test (the `for` loop).  So this test should largely be CPU-bound and not affected by differences in I/O implementation between MacOS and Ubuntu.
- I ran the test several times and the result seems fairly consistent.
- There is no other notable system load.

Comment: Can you test again with a `for` loop instead (`time for ((i=0; i < 1000000; i++)); do :; done`)? That should be interesting...

Comment: @xhienne The results are similar: >twice faster on the VM.  In fact the `for (( ))` version took about twice as long as the `for x in { }` on both host and VM.

Comment: It's twice as long but if you consider the memory usage, you'll see a huge difference (change 1000000 to 100000000 if that's not obvious enough). But I expected your host to be quicker than the VM in my test, I'm disappointed

Comment: I guess your two cores are dedicated to the VM and that no other process on your host can use these two cores. Can you dedicate a core to your `bash` process on your host, just to be sure your Mac is not using it to do other tasks?

Comment: @xhienne I'm not sure there is a way I can have MacOS dedicate one core to a particular process and explicitly exclude all other processes.  I think we just have to trust that the scheduler will do its best to schedule the CPU-bound process as much as it can.  We can see this - `top` shows the bash process use ~99.8 of one CPU while the test is running.

Comment: At this time, my only conclusion is that the compiler used on your MacOS to compile `bash` is less efficient than gcc on Ubuntu. Or the compiler flags are chosen less carefully.